# Can wit.ai, api.ai etc generate its own conversations by training or are every conversation static structured by stories the "bot" owner created?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, wit.ai, dialogflow-es

Can wit.ai, api.ai etc. generate its own conversations by training or are every conversation static structured by stories the "bot" owner created ?

Im in the search for a botting tool that can generate conversations based on what it has learned, and the more conversations it has the better it gets to replying to users, where human-like hour long conversations could be a possibility.

I've looked at wit.ai, api.ai and others like it, but they seem to be based upon stories which typically ends up into some command-like stuff, like ordering a pizza. Though they can be made to remember who they speak to and other entity information.

Do i have to structure a hundred of stories or is it possible to just make a base and make it learn from there, and perhaps add more stories in the future based upon old conversations to make it smarter. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many parts to the answer.

On the one hand, there is [Mitsuku](http://www.mitsuku.com), which probably comes closest to what you are aspiring to. From what I understand, Mitsuku has been built over a long time using plenty of hand coded rules - a bit like the hundreds of stories you are talking about. There isn't a Mitsuku-as-a-service that I know of, at least not yet.

On the other hand, there are bot building frameworks like api.ai, wit.ai and others which are using machine learning to effectively do two main things - intent mapping (what is the subject the user is talking about) and entity extraction (mentions of proper nouns). In combination, it can be quite helpful for task oriented chatbots but not sufficient for the kind of truly conversational chatbots you are trying to build.

I would also encourage you to check out the following YouTube video, specifically the segment where the presenter talks about generative vs retrieval based chatbots.

https://youtu.be/SvV57fuL_M0?t=202

Also, api.ai also has something called "prebuilt domains", which have knowledge about a few domains. There is a "small talk" domain included, but if you look under the hood, it basically expects the bot programmer to fill out a questionnaire which goes from 0% to 100% complete based on usual expected questions.

You also ask about using history to make your bot smarter. If you are prepared to go through the chat logs, bot building frameworks such as API.AI allow you to start with something narrow and go on to make a pretty interesting bot by doing training (hard to explain, take a look at their interface). But this also means a) you are willing to spend a good amount of time improving the bot and b) you can actually drive enough traffic to your bot to field a wide range of questions.

Its my view that there is quite a lot of hype as to what chatbots can do. I think they are quite useful, but they are hardly conversational in the way humans think of conversations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the information, guess I have some training to do. :)